# How to create kiosk-mode iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, kiosk, autostart

I'd like to run an app in the KIOSK mode, so that it

1. auto-starts after starting the device
2. re-starts after app crash/power loss/etc.

Any ideas how to do this on a [probably jailbroken?] iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method would be to create a mobilesubstrate extension that runs inside SpringBoard and throws up its own `UIWindow`.

Create a `static __attribute__((constructor))` function and inside register for `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification`.  After receiving the notification, 99% of the standard iPhone SDK will work as-is.

Comment: thanks, can you provide more code/resources on creating mobilesubstrate extensions?

Comment: MobileSubstrate is simple enough; just compile your project with the `-dynamiclib` linker flag, ignore the codesign error, and move the compiled binary from `build/.../MyExt.app/MyExt` to `/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/MyExt.dylib` on your device.  If you are just creating your own `UIWindow` and such, the standard SDK will do; if you want to interact with SpringBoard itself, you will need to get SpringBoard headers (either via class-dump or some other source).

Comment: Is there any precedent of applications that do this? I'd love to see a GitHub link to some example code.

Answer (score 2):

It will have to be jailbroken because the standard OS won't give you that level of control.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already thinking jailbreak, perhaps look into launchd on the phone as whatever starts up Springboard could also probably be made to start up your app after.